# Django save method is overwriting field values

Tags: django, database, oracle, django-models

I have a model that is overwriting a field value during the save opperation, I don't know if that happens during the communication with the database or its a pure Django problem.

My bugged model:

```
class Classificacao(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, verbose_name="Item", db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='seq_prod')
    is_valid = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

In order to identify the bug I overwrited the save method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print(self.is_valid)
    super(Classificacao, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    print(self.is_valid)
```

When I created an instance of the class by the following code the overwrited 'save' prints the above:

```
classificacao_nova = Classificacao.objects.create(
    item=item,
    created_at=datetime.datetime.now()
)
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

With debug mode on the following inser query was shown:

```
(0.001) QUERY = 'INSERT INTO "CALCULO_CLASSIFICACAO" ("SEQ_PROD", "IS_VALID", "CREATED_AT", "UPDATED_AT") VALUES (:arg4, :arg7, :arg0, :arg2) RETURNING "CALCULO_CLASSIFICACAO"."ID" INTO :arg1' - PARAMS = (1288767006, False, Oracle_datetime(2019, 9, 10, 10, 23, 2, 359822), Oracle_datetime(2019, 9, 10, 10, 23, 2, 359836), '<django.db.backends.oracle.utils.InsertIdVar object at 0x7fb99f578be0>'); args=(1288767006, False, Oracle_datetime(2019, 9, 10, 10, 23, 2, 359822), Oracle_datetime(2019, 9, 10, 10, 23, 2, 359836), <django.db.backends.oracle.utils.InsertIdVar object at 0x7fb99f578be0>)
```

Notice the **False** in the insert.

Any ideas of what is going on?

PS.: The database default for the is_valid column is 1.

Comment: When does this happen? You say in other parts of the code the output is True True, so in which part of the code is this?

Comment: `created_at` is `auto_now_add=True` but you are passing a value in. Does it make any difference if you don't pass the `created_at` value in when you create the model instance or if you change `auto_now_add=True` to use `default` instead?

Comment: @dirkgroten I've removed that from the post, in fact it doesn't matter.

Comment: @MT0 I've tried to remove both from the model and from the create code and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just found the solution:
Just changed the field name from *is_valid* to *classificacao_valida*.

I believe that the problem was caused cus a variable or method on the **models.Model** is named is_valid, which ended overwriting my class is_valid values.